# How do I get all the tags on a headline, including the inherited ones?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

The [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-inheritance.html) says that a child headline will inherit all the tags from its parent.

What function should I use to give me a list of all these tags?

`org-get-tags` and `org-get-local-tags` both seem to be giving me only the tag that is present only on the current headline.

Comment: There may be other functions, but a quick look at `org-get-tags-at` leads me to believe this may be useful for obtaining a complete list of tags -- have a look at the doc-string and see if that will suit your needs (including the two optional arguments, the latter of which relates to inherited tags) ...  I don't use inherited tags, so I don't have a quick way to test this.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you please post it as a solution so that I can accept it?

Comment: Note: starting in Org 9.2, `org-get-tags` will return the inherited tags as well (see https://orgmode.org/Changes.html#org8cf98ef or search for "org-get-tags meaning change"). You can get only tags set on the headline by running `(org-get-tags nil t)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `org-get-tags-at` is a means by which to obtain a list of tags that can include or exclude those that are inherited based upon the second optional argument `LOCAL`.  For a description of this particular function, see the doc-string:  `C-h f` or `M-x describe-function`.

Comment: `org-get-tags-at` is obsolete since Org 9.2; use `org-get-tags` instead.